# Google Analytics intrusive comment

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics

I have a WordPress site and Google Analytics installed. However when I open my site from Google Chrome I see this comment at the top of the page: /** Google Analytics tracking code begins here **/ /** Google Analytics tracking code ends here **/
I have checked my php files but can't manage to find where that comment is located and fix the problem.

Can anyone take a look please and give me a hint, Thank you very much. 
My site is https://tecnicadevoz.com

Comment: I don't see that on your site front-end. Not only that, but I don't see any mention of Analytics in your source code either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are two common causes for this issue.

- The first one is your browser cache. Sometimes your browser (specially Google Chrome) will show you a cached copy of your website instead of showing the new one. To resolve this issue, you need to simply hit CTRL + F5 (or Cmd + R in Mac) buttons on your keyboard to reload the page.
- The second and most likely cause of this issue is poorly configured WordPress caching plugin. To see if a caching plugin is causing this problem, you need to see if you’re using a caching plugin on your site.

The first thing you can do is try to Empty All Caches using your cache plugin settings area.

Comment: Thank you Vasim, I've done all the suggestions you gave me, unfortunately the comment still there. I appreciate your answer.